# Sybase:-where to save a new database

Tags: sqlanywhere

I have downloaded "SQL Anywhere-12" trial version from the Sybase website. 
I use Windows Vista

It installed itself in two locations.The Sybase related folders are in:-

```
 1)  "C:\Program Files\.."
         -sybase
         -SQL Anywhere 12


 2) "C:\Users\Public\Documents\SQL Anywhere 12\Samples"
         -DBISQL 12.0.1
         -SQL Anywhere 12
         -Sybase Central 6.1.0
```

Is it how Sybase downloads itself? Or was there any error in downloading?

The reason I ask is **I am not sure where to save any "NEW sybase-DATABASE" created**?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: FYI it is almost never appropriate to ask a question on both StackOverflow _and_ ServerFault. I've answered the question in both places, but this question is more appropriate for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in `C:\Users` is sample databases, example code, scripts, stuff like that. The actual software is installed in `C:\Program Files`.

For SQL Anywhere-specific questions, you may want to check out [sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com).

*Disclaimer: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*